# Restrict Azure timer trigger running from multiple instances

Tags: c#, azure-functions, singleton, azure-app-service-plans, timer-trigger

I have an Azure timer trigger function hosted in an App Service plan (I3 : 5).

By default App Service plan instance count has been set to 5.

So whenever timer trigger starts, it is starting from all of the five instances parallelly.

I want to restrict the timer trigger running to a single instance.

I made the below line of code on top of the timer trigger function name:

```
[Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
```

But it is not restricting to single instance. Again timer trigger running in all of the 5 instances.

Appreciate your comments and answers.

Comment: check this doc if helps https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer.md

Comment: Try with only `[Singleton]` and check once.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#scale-out) clearly says

*If a function app scales out to multiple instances, only a single instance of a timer-triggered function is run across all instances. It will not trigger again if there is an outstanding invocation is still running.*

If you are observing a different behavior, it may mean that something may have not been setup/configured properly.